# Issue with copying postgresql tables in liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have table1 with columns(id, name, age) and table2 with columns(id, name, age). I decide to transfer data from table1 to table2 because I want to use table1 for other things. Both tables created with liquibase.

Script main body: `<changeSet id="1" <sql> INSERT INTO table2(id, name, age) SELECT id, name, age FROM table1 </sql> </changeSet>`.

After running project with spring.liquibase script work out but nothing was transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your dataset file (.xml) to the master.xml file?